I'm getting Invalid_grant when trying to access the acccess token and refresh token by OAuth2.0
I'm trying to get the access token and refresh token from google oauth2. Let me take you through one step at a time until I got the error. What I'm trying to do is straight out of documentation

google console settings and credentials are well set.
￼

Successfully received auth code using the following url that I pasted on my browser.


https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
scope=https://mail.google.com/&
access_type=offline&
include_granted_scopes=true&
response_type=code&
state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
redirect_uri=http://localhost&
client_id=
code=4/0AcvDMrAjHZ9AeAhiQiE533rWoe6Hk4gmetvjfv-cY6nXMaaFB8BoVrxL-9-2ZLqjfMh50A is the output that is got.

trying to make a curl request using this auth code that I received from the previous step

curl --location 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data 'code=4/0AcvDMrAjHZ9AeAhiQiE533rWoe6Hk4gmetvjfv-cY6nXMaaFB8BoVrxL-9-2ZLqjfMh50A&
client_id=&
client_secret=&
redirect_uri=http://localhost&
grant_type=authorization_code'
Following is the output that I'm getting: 
{
"error": "unsupported_grant_type",
"error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
So, this is the error that i'm getting. I have rechecked my client id, secret, code, redirect_uri and everything looks correct. I'm not able to debug this issue.
Could someone please help me resolve it?

I see spaces in your URLs. Are those typos, or are you actually copying and pasting URLs? Because honestly I don't think they're supposed to be there.

Actually that's the issue. Thanks for pointing out.
